# Adding automatic labelling of boundaries to region plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

Is it possible to automatically label boundaries of a `RegionPlot` in a similar style to `PlotLabels` by the equality that describes them. Ideally even splitting any `Or` statement to the relevant part that holds at that boundary. So that for example in the plot below

```
RegionPlot[{x > y || x^2 + y^2 < 1, y > 2 x || x^2 + y^2 < 2}, {x, -2,
   2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

The straight lines have labels `"x = y"` and `"y = 2 x"` and the round parts `"x^2 + y^2 = 1"` and `"x^2 + y^2 = 2"`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Manually adjust the positions and offsets in `Arrowheads` and `Text` to place the labels on the boundary curves:

```
RegionPlot[{x > y || x^2 + y^2 < 1, y > 2 x || x^2 + y^2 < 2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> 
    {2 ->  Arrowheads[{{Automatic, .75, 
        Graphics[{Text[Style[ToString[x^2 + y^2 == 2, TraditionalForm], Black,  16],
          {0, 0}, {0, -2}, {-1, 0}]}]}, 
       {Automatic, .53, 
        Graphics[{Text[Style[ToString[y == 2 x, TraditionalForm], Black, 16], 
          {.5, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}]}]}}], 
    1 -> Arrowheads[{{Automatic, .25, 
        Graphics[{Text[Style[ToString[x^2 + y^2 == 1, TraditionalForm], Black,  16], 
         {0, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}]}]}, 
       {Automatic, .1, 
        Graphics[{Text[Style[ToString[y == x, TraditionalForm], Black, 16], 
         {.5, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}]}]}}]}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

**2.** Use `ListPlot` with `Callout`s and `Show` with `RegionPlot` output:

```
labels = Style[#, 16]& /@ TraditionalForm /@ 
    {y == x, x^2 + y^2 == 1, y == 2 x, x^2 + y^2 == 2};

points = {{-1.5, -1.3}, {-1.25, .2}, {.5, 1.3}, {1.1, -1.25}};

angles = {45, 60, 60, 60};

rp =  RegionPlot[{x > y || x^2 + y^2 < 1,  y > 2 x || x^2 + y^2 < 2}, 
     {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];


Show[rp, ListPlot[MapThread[Callout[# , #2, 
    LeaderSize -> {{0}, {0, #3 Degree}}, Background -> Opacity[0]] &, 
  {points, labels, angles}], PlotStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

**3.**  Interactively position the labels using `LocatorPane`:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = points}, LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], rp, Appearance -> labels]]
```

[image]